# A congruence in multiple variables

Tags: elementary-number-theory

The following was a question on a homework assignment that has already been submitted/collected.

Show that the following equation has no integer solutions.

$x_1^{11}+x_2^{11}+...+x_9^{11}+x_{10}^{11}=230000000000011$

Hint: reduce mod a suitable prime.

I tried reducing mod primes less than or equal to 11. Larger values will leave our exponents untouched which I don't believe is desirable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good prime to use is $p=23$. Note that $x^{11}$ is congruent to $0$, $1$, or $-1$ modulo $23$. For if $x$ is not divisible by $23$, then $x^{22}\equiv 1\pmod{23}$, and therefore $(x^{11})^2\equiv 1$, which forces $x^{11}\equiv \pm 1$.

No combination of $10$ of $0$, $1$, or $-1$ is congruent to $11$ modulo $23$.